# See if a SharedPreference variable is null or not

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Global Variable:

```
SharedPreferences prefs;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
```

Saved during `onDestory()`:

```
editor.putInt("InfType", rgTypeOfInf.getCheckedRadioButtonId()); //saving value
```

Being called during `onCreate()`:

```
rgTypeOfInf = (RadioGroup) mFrame2.findViewById(R.id.rgType);
rgTypeOfInf.check(prefs.getInt("InfType", 2131230725)); //retrieving the value
```

How can I check when my app loads to see if the saved variable exist or if it's `null`. If it exist, check the radio button of the radiogroup otherwise if it's `null`, check the radiogroup[0] position by default?

My XML file:

```
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rgType"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbBridge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Bridge" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbTunnel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Tunnel" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbHighway"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Highway" />
    </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: [`SharedPreferences#contains(String key)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#contains%28java.lang.String%29)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put:

```
int checked = -1;
RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgType);
for(int i = 0; i < rg.getChildCount(); i++){
  if(((RadioButton)rg.getChildAt(i)).isChecked()){
     checked = i;
  }
}
editor.putInt("InfType", checked);
```

Retrieve:

```
int InfType = prefs.getInt("InfType", -1);
RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgType);
if(InfType > -1) {
  ((RadioButton)rg.getChildAt(InfType)).toggle();
} else{
  ((RadioButton)rg.getChildAt(0)).toggle();
}
```

Havent tested

Used:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getInt(java.lang.String,%20int)

Comment: Do you know how to RESET the value to default?

Comment: @ZahidH remove stored value

Comment: Couldnt I take out the `RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) rgTypeOfInf;` from each code in the `onCreate()` since I was already calling it before? (Nevermind it is crashing my app)

Comment: I have three radio group and I did the same thing for all three. Two of them works for retrieve but the third one is causing my app to FC. Any idea?

Comment: @what does logcat say?

Comment: I Might have figured it out :/ (I was using `checked` for all three. Once I changed to three separate variable, it worked fine)

Answer (score 2):

So you have a 'default' setting already if its null

See, your `rgTypeOfInf.check(prefs.getInt("InfType", 2131230725));` has 2131230725 as the default value of the pref if it does not exist.

So, you can set it to something like -1, then say

```
int type = prefs.getInt("InfType", -1);

if (type == -1){
   //was never set
} else{
  //...
}
```

Comment: I added the XML file in my question. By default `Bridge` is auto selected. So for example I chose `Tunnel` as an option and I leave the view and come back, `Tunnel` should be checked because I saved the value. If I come to the app for the first time, `Bridge` should be checked because it's the default unless I change it. But when I load my app none of the radio button in the group is selected.